# Not able to attach on user defined bridge attach command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, bridge, user-defined

I tried to attach in container. But while i attach it's come out.
Here is the network below

```
NETWORK ID     NAME            DRIVER    SCOPE
7ab1dac4166d   alpine-net      bridge    local
```

Below are my containers

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND              CREATED          STATUS              PORTS     NAMES
4f98c3758144   httpd     "httpd-foreground"   23 minutes ago   Up 3 seconds        80/tcp    alpine4
a00e9603190e   httpd     "httpd-foreground"   23 minutes ago   Up 23 minutes       80/tcp    alpine3
a02ac156f310   httpd     "httpd-foreground"   23 minutes ago   Up 23 minutes       80/tcp    alpine2
55a0395dc0bc   httpd     "httpd-foreground"   24 minutes ago   Up About a minute   80/tcp    alpine1
```

I am trying to connect alpine1. But not working. After press ctrl+c container got shutdown.

```
root@ip-172-31-35-240:~# docker network connect alpine-net 4f98c3758144
Error response from daemon: endpoint with name alpine4 already exists in network alpine-net
root@ip-172-31-35-240:~# docker attach alpine1

^C[Wed Sep 28 17:38:25.604430 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 140167697374528] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
root@ip-172-31-35-240:~# docker attach alpine1
You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first
root@ip-172-31-35-240:~# docker attach alpine2

^C[Wed Sep 28 17:47:57.649545 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 140336080485696] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
root@ip-172-31-35-240:~# docker attach a00e9603190e
^C[Wed Sep 28 17:48:56.424446 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 140629127331136] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

How to attach it? In default bridge it's working. User defined bridge not working

Try1:  I recreated server and I have only one network. Below that I have 2 container in this network. When I try again getting shutdown. If you please help to fix this.

Network List :
root@ip-172-31-32-242:~# docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME       DRIVER    SCOPE
7ee777e7a9d6   bridge     bridge    local
694493b04e19   gold-net   bridge    local
75c9930ac3df   host       host      local
6ffae4da13f6   none       null      local

Listing the containers
root@ip-172-31-32-242:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND              CREATED              STATUS              PORTS     NAMES
0f275cb17da4   httpd     "httpd-foreground"   49 seconds ago       Up 48 seconds       80/tcp    apache4
d3bf64d7f751   httpd     "httpd-foreground"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   80/tcp    apache3
0ddd638f1c92   httpd     "httpd-foreground"   2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes        80/tcp    apache2
b09daeeb17b8   httpd     "httpd-foreground"   2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes        80/tcp    apache1

Failure Result:
root@ip-172-31-32-242:~# docker container attach apache1
^C[Thu Sep 29 06:44:56.692274 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 140043293744448] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
root@ip-172-31-32-242:~#
root@ip-172-31-32-242:~#
root@ip-172-31-32-242:~#
root@ip-172-31-32-242:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND              CREATED          STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
0f275cb17da4   httpd     "httpd-foreground"   21 minutes ago   Up 21 minutes              80/tcp    apache4
d3bf64d7f751   httpd     "httpd-foreground"   21 minutes ago   Up 21 minutes              80/tcp    apache3
0ddd638f1c92   httpd     "httpd-foreground"   22 minutes ago   Up 22 minutes              80/tcp    apache2
b09daeeb17b8   httpd     "httpd-foreground"   23 minutes ago   Exited (0) 8 minutes ago             apache1
root@ip-172-31-32-242:~#

Comment: how did you start the container. The errors says there is already one in the network with that name. Did you start it with the `--network` flag?

Comment: You may find it cleaner to just delete and recreate the containers on the correct network.

Comment: @DavidMaze I destroyed server and recreated. I have only one network. Under that I created 2 containers. Still not able to attach. 

NETWORK ID     NAME       DRIVER    SCOPE
7ee777e7a9d6   bridge     bridge    local
694493b04e19   gold-net   bridge    local
75c9930ac3df   host       host      local
6ffae4da13f6   none       null      local